# Actionscript equivalent of Python's class "set"

Tags: actionscript, types

In Python, there is a class called "set". I realize that similar functionality could be implemented in AS by a Dictionary where only the keys matter.

But it seems that this should be a built-in type for ActionScript. Unfortunately, it's nearly impossible to search for. Before I go off and code up my own "set" class, does it already exist?

Comment: Python's [`set`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set) has a lot of functionality - are you just looking for "no duplicates" or will you use the other functionality, e.g. `isdisjoint`?

Comment: @Seth all I need are methods to add an element, check to see if it contains an element, remove an element, and iterate over all elements. The main downside to rolling my own class is that (afaik) there's no way to do something like `foreach(var obj in instance_of_a_custom_class)`

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with ActionScript, but there's an [implementation here](http://www.as3dp.com/2008/09/04/the-iterator-pattern-flexible-implementation-of-collections/) that might be worth a read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not.  But you should be careful - relying too much on a user-defined data type (sic) could lead to problems (read: bloated code), eg, if you're accepting varying types as arguments.  That said, creating a helper class to deal with Python-like sets is probably the best way to go, though the best way would be likely, as you said, to use objects (Dictionary).